# How can I separate areas with floats from each other?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float

I'm struggling with Bootstrap rows and columns in a SharePoint web site. The problem is that I can't and don't want to change the styling that originates from SharePoint, but still be able to use the Bootstrap grid in a part of the page.

I've tried to illustrate the problem without Bootstrap and SharePoint. Here's the JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/knLjyhe4/

Below is a complete illustration of my example. The problem is that once I use a row to separate element B from C, D and E, the height of side element A affects the first row's height, which I don't want. I want element C to appear immediately below element B. The second example is how it looks before I add the div.row elements.

[image]

Below is the HTML and CSS for the isolated example. I had hoped that I could style the div.main element somehow so that the float of A doesn't affect the float of B-E at all. But I can't figure it out.

Please note that I'm sure there are several solutions if I start to change the HTML and styles (like using position), but I really just want to know if there is a way in CSS where the div.main element gets "its own" floating area, without being affected by the A element's float.

```html
<style>
  section {
    width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .block {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #339;
    color: #fff;
    width: 140px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .side {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
  }
  .main {
    margin-left: 240px;
  }
  .row:after {
    display: table;
    content: ' ';
    clear: both;
  }
</style>
<section>
  <div class="side block">This is element A in problematic example. I want element C immediately below element B, regardless of the height of this element</div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="block">This is element B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="block">This is element C</div>
      <div class="block">This is element D</div>
      <div class="block">This is element E</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="side block">This is element A when it works but without rows</div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="block">This is element B</div>
    <div class="block">This is element C</div>
    <div class="block">This is element D</div>
    <div class="block">This is element E</div>
    <div class="block">This is element F</div>
    <div class="block">This is element G</div>
    <div class="block">This is element H</div>
    <div class="block">This is element I</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: have you considered using flexbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be working if you change your CSS for `.main` to this (`display: table-row;`):

```
.main {
  margin-left: 240px;
  display: table-row;
}
```

Updated JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/knLjyhe4/3/)

**UPDATE 1**

Changed `table` to `table-row` since it did not work in IE10.

**UPDATE 2**

For future reference, the final solution used in SharePoint / O365 looked something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/knLjyhe4/4/):

HTML (`.container` is a bootstrap container)

```
<div id="DeltaPlaceHolderMain">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="inner-container">
            <!--Your content here-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container .inner-container {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Looks great, but doesn't work in IE10 which unfortunately might still be used by clients. The spacing is gone, but instead all div.block elements are rendered in a single column below each other.

Comment: Yes, the answer to my question is in fact this: put contents of the div.main element in a table with a single cell, or make the div.main element into a table itself by the display:table-row style. This will effectively "reset" the floating interactions I was having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

The .main needs to be float:left and it needs to have less px to width.

Try defines

```
  .side {width:30%; float:left;}
  .main{width:70%; float:left; margin-left:0; }
```

Don't forget to clean the margin-left of .main

Answer (score 0):

The `clear: both` property on the `row:after` pseudoclass is causing your second row to jump down below the left-floated `side` element.

In bootstrap you should use classname `col-md-4` on your `side` element, classname `col-md-8` on your `main` element, and remove the `float: left` property from your `side` element.  This will give you 2 columns, one for `side` which is 4 grids wide and one for `main` which is 8 grids wide.  Your rows should function as you expect once the float is gone.

```
<style>
  section {
    width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .block {
    background-color: #339;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
  }
</style>

<section class="row">
  <div class="block col-md-4">This is element A</div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="block col-md-6">This is element B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="block col-md-6">This is element C</div>
      <div class="block col-md-6">This is element D</div>
      <div class="block col-md-6">This is element E</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

In general, with bootstrap you don't want to float things.  Also, instead of setting element widths explicitly, it is better to use the `.col-` classes to fit them into the bootstrap grid system.

Comment: Since this is in SharePoint, it would be preferred if the CSS for `.side` could be left alone.

Comment: If that's the case, I recommend dropping Bootstrap.  The .row class is causing your issue and you only need that class if you are using the bootstrap grid system.